# Converting Latitude/Longitude pairs into Belgian Lambert 1972 coordinates (theory & implementation)

Tags: python, geolocation, coordinates, coordinate-systems

How can I convert Latitude/Longitude pairs into Belgian Lambert 1972 coordinates?

First, even though I searched for a formula online for such a conversion, I could not find any formula. From a theoretical perspective, can you shed some light on formula(s) needed to convert latitude/longitude pairs into Belgian Lambert 1972 coordinates?

Second, it would be great to know whether the above-mentioned conversion can be implemented with an already existing Python package.

Finally, let's say that I want to convert the latitude/longitude of Brussel (city) into Lambert 1972 coordinates: How would the aforementioned pair of Brussel's latitude/longitude (i.e., latitude = 50.8427501 & longitude = 4.3515499) look like in terms of Belgian Lambert 1972 coordinates?

Comment: Well the coordinates are the same, but the projection differs. You could use [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html) to set epsg to [Lambert 72](https://epsg.io/31370)

Comment: Or better, Proj4 (proj.org) is the way to convert projections. Nearly all open sourcer projects (and other) use it. There is also a python port which BTW it is a dependency of geopandas. Theory is complex. In any case latitude and longitude are vague terms, you need to specify your definition (so ellipsoid, origin points, coordinates on it [or projections and coordinates on projections], and ev. parametric data [e.g. time dependent]).  Some geographic office in Belgium should have published also short formula (numerically accurate) to e.g. WGS84 [the GPS coordinates], but you can use proj.